# Devise - changed authentication_keys to :login after upgrade from restful_authentication - invalid email or password error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I recently upgraded my Rails app from restful_authentication to devise, and by default the devise login page worked (authenticating with email).  I don't want to authenticate via email though and when I moved authentication on 'login' field on the user model, it no longer works and I get the following error:

> Invalid email or password.

Devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :trackable,
         :encryptable, :encryptor => :restful_authentication_sha1
  attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :twitter_name, :twitter_id, :atoken, :asecret
```

new.haml (for session)

```
  = form_tag session_path, :class => 'enter_form' do
    %label.form_label_small{:for => "login", :style => "color: #336699"} username
    %br/
    = text_field_tag 'login', @login, :class => 'input_style_state', :style => 'width: 250px;'
    .clear{:style => 'height: 4px'}
    %label.form_label_small{:for => "password", :style => "color: #336699"} password
    %br/
    = password_field_tag 'password', nil, :style => 'width: 250px;'
    .clear{:style => 'height: 4px'}
    %p{:style => "padding: 0; margin:0;"}
      = check_box_tag 'remember_me', '1', @remember_me, :style => 'padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0'
      = label_tag 'remember_me', 'remember me'
    .clear{:style => "height: 8px"} 
    %a.button.submit_form{:href => '/login'}
      %span{:style => 'width: 40px'}
        login
```

I've had a similar problem with another project.  I imagine if :login was being picked up successfully as the authentication key, that the error message would say 'invalid login or passowrd' rather then 'invalid email or password'

Any ideas on how to hunt this down?  My error logs don't say anything.  Here's the log:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Nov 10 13:46:13 -0500 2011
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"AMole3YOhXPuOQGX27W1Mr7c18XR1Xk9DUF6JvstbZA=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "login"=>"aressidi", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`login` = 'aressidi' LIMIT 1
  NavAd Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `nav_ads`.* FROM `nav_ads`
Completed   in 34ms
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"AMole3YOhXPuOQGX27W1Mr7c18XR1Xk9DUF6JvstbZA=", "utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "login"=>"aressidi", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

Comment: My issue was solved when I restarted the server after running the migrations. For some reason, the server cached something and would not accept the credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Devise error messages aren't generated dynamically, so the error message doesn't necessarily indicate that it's looking at the wrong field for authentication. See http://asciicasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

Also take note of which version of ruby you're using. Devise doesn't seem to correctly use it's config.authentication_keys setting with Ruby 1.9.3. It started working immediately once I switched back to Ruby 1.9.2.